# Send 2 array to view in sailjs

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I am new to sails.js and when I'm trying to learn it by making a simple web app, I encountered a problem. My app is about class management. My model has 3 table: student, course and list. The student table save information about students, course save information about courses. The list.table save information about which student is in a course and their mark, their absent days in this class. I used res.view() and it worked for any view that need one array. However, when I try to write function which need information from 2 model: student and course, res.view() didnt help (or I dont know to do it properly)

```
module.exports = {
   'new': function(req, res, next) {
   Course.find(function foundCourses (err, courses) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     res.view({courses: courses});
   });
   /* Student.find(function foundStudents (err, students) {
     if (err) return next(err);
     res.view({
       students: students
     });
   }); */
   },
   //more other code here
};
```

There, I want to send both array to view but I dont know how. Sails.js only let me send one array if I do like that. Please help me . Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call `res.view` twice. You need to gather all data first and than send it to view.

2 methods:

```
module.exports = {
    'new': function(req, res, next) {
         var foundCourses = function (err, courses) {
             if (err) return next(err);
             Student.find(function foundStudents (err, students) {
                 if (err) return next(err);
                 res.view({
                     courses: courses,
                     students: students
                 });
             });
         });

         Course.find(foundCourses);
    },
    //more other code here
};
```

or you can use `async.parallel`

```
module.exports = {
    'new': function(req, res, next) {
        var dataCallback = function (err, data) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            var courses = data[0];
            var students = data[1];
            res.view({
                courses: courses,
                students: students
            });
        };

        async.parallel([
            function(callback) {
                Course.find(callback);
            },
            function(callback) {
                Student.find(callback);
            }
        ],dataCallback);
    },
};
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. I trying to learn this by myself and this is one of my cheesy mistake :D